# How to type the simply typed lambda calculus term (S K K)

Tags: haskell, lambda, functional-programming, k-combinator, s-combinator

I am attempting to implement a simply typed lambda calculus type checker. When running sanity tests I tried typing (S K K) and my type checker throws this error:

`TypeMismatch {firstType = t -> t, secondType = t -> t -> t}`

The offending term is clearly the (S K K)

`(\x:t -> t -> t.\y:t -> t.\z:t.x z (y z)) (\x:t.\y:t.x) (\\x:t.\y:t.x)`

I think the problem arises from a lack of polymorphism because when I type check this haskell code it works fine:

```
k x y = x
s x y z = x z (y z)
test = s k k -- type checks
```

but if I specialize the type:

```
k :: () -> () -> ()
k x y = x
s :: (() -> () -> ()) -> (() -> ()) -> () -> ()
s x y z = x z (y z)
test = s k k -- doesn't type check
```

Just for reference my type system is a simple as it gets:

`data Type = T | TArr Type Type`

[full source](https://github.com/mckeankylej/LambdaCubeTraversal/tree/master/src/SimplyTyped)

Comment: I wonder what the type of S (SKK)(SKK) might be.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I will steal the ideas from [a previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32385204/791604) to show how to ask ghci your question. But first I am going to reformulate your question slightly.

In Haskell, we have

```
s :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
k :: a -> b -> a
```

and the question we want to ask is "What do these types look like after type-checking `s k k`?". More to the point, if we rewrite them with distinct unification variables,

```
s :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
k :: d -> e -> d
k :: f -> g -> f
s k k :: h
```

then the question becomes a unification one: we are trying to unify the type of `s` with the type it's being used at -- namely `(d -> e -> d) -> (f -> g -> f) -> h`. Now that we have a unification question in hand, we can ask in the format showed in my other answer:

```
> :{
| :t undefined
| ::   ((a -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c))
|    ~ ((d -> e -> d) -> (f -> g -> f) -> h)
| => (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h)
| :}
undefined
::   ((a -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c))
   ~ ((d -> e -> d) -> (f -> g -> f) -> h)
=> (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h)
  :: (f, g -> f, f, f, g -> f, f, g, f -> f)
```

And now we can see why your version doesn't work: in your version, you've instantiated all polymorphic variables to the base type `T`; but since `b ~ g -> f`, `e ~ g -> f`, and `h ~ f -> f` are manifestly arrow types, that certainly isn't going to work! However, any choices for `f` and `g` will work if we respect the substitution above; in particular if we choose `f ~ T` and `g ~ T`, then we have

```
s :: (T -> (T -> T) -> T) -> (T -> (T -> T)) -> (T -> T)
k1 :: T -> (T -> T) -> T
k2 :: T -> T -> T
s k1 k2 :: T -> T
```